# Not able to invoke OnFailure function of Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Button on the view, clicking this button will submit the Ajax Form i.e.

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("SuspendAction", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "btn-suspend-unsuspend", OnSuccess = "onLoadData", OnFailure = "onSuspendFailure", OnBegin = "onBeginDataLoad", LoadingElementId = "loading" }, new { data_message = strings.DashboardAccountStatusSuspendedMsg, data_failureMessage = strings.OperationFailureErrorMsg }))
                {


                }
```

SuspendAction is an Action in the Home Controller that returns the PartialResultView. Now the issue is, This action should return a failure message and OnFailure Function should get invoked. Would like to know how to achieve this functionality.

Like

```
public PartialViewResult SuspendAction()
{
  try
  {
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
{
  //should trigger OnFailure function.
}
}
```

Comment: You are catching the exception in the controller so there is no failure in the client.

Comment: @stephen would like add a logic to invoke on failure from this catch block by passing the error Message that's wat we want to achieve.

Comment: Then do not catch the exception, or throw another exception with the message you want, or return a HttpStatusCode indicating the error e.g. `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(....)`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke will this comply with PartialViewResult Return Type

Comment: Yes (an for any other type of `ActionResult`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnFailure method occured when the response status code is not 2XX.
At the catch block change reponse status code to 4XX:

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
```